# Does log4j2 provide any mechanism to rollover file every day and archive log files at the end of the month

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Does log4j2 provide any mechanism to rollover file every day and archive log files at the end of the month?
I am able to achieve daily rollover but after a month I want to compress all logs and move to archive folder

Comment: Yes, log4j2 provides a *mechanism* for something like that, it's called a **custom appender**, in that you write your own appender to do exactly what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Log4j doesn't currently support that but it would be great to create a Jira issue for it as it would be a neat addition. Log4j already supports Actions being evaluated on every rollover. The only Action plugin currently implemented is the DeleteAction. But Log4j has built in Actions to compress files on every rollover, but these are not plugins as they were created before generic actions were added. It would be fairly simply to create a CompressAction that invokes the existing compress actions using the existing PathConditions or by creating a new PathCondition.